# Deploy de sitio WP en banahosting con dominio .cl

Tags: wordpress, webservice, servidor, deployment, dominio

Estoy armándole un sitio a un amigo en WP, el tema es que el quiere un dominio .cl, ya lo compré y ahora quiero contratar el servidor (en banahosting), el problema es que me pide el codigo auth para transferir el dominio pero ese va a estar habilitado en 30 días según Nic Chile ¿puedo contratar el servidor, ponerme a trabajar y después asociar el dominio?

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: No deberias transferir el dominio.. el dominio es tuyo... deberias apuntar nic a donde este tu servidor.. ojo, porque a veces esos servidores quieren "robarte" el dominio..

Comment: Exacto. En la gestión del dominio, puedes configurar los registros A, CNAME, MX, etc... para que apunten a las URL que tu proveedor de hosting indique para recibir ese tráfico. Así, cuando alguien resuelva `midominio.cl`, Nic Chile le va a decir _Ah sí, vaya a esta otra url y ahí encuenta el sitio_... no tienes que transferirlo y el hosting está en la obligación de indicarte cómo configurar tu dominio para que apunte a tu hosting

Comment: no necesitaras transferir el dominio, si ya lo tienes basta con reenviar el registro A a la ip del server en los DNS, si lo que quieres es que tu host controle los DNS entonces solo cambia los Name Servers por los del host y luego configura tus DNS, no es necesario transferir el dominio para hacer eso.

Comment: `¿puedo contratar el servidor, ponerme a trabajar y después asociar el dominio?` Sí.